# Codename One action every N seconds

Tags: codenameone

I'm working on my app developed with codename one. Now I need to perform an action every 10 seconds to update: Is there a sort of timer-thread which run always in background every N seconds?

Answer (score 1):

If you need that action to happen off the EDT you can use `java.util.Timer`. If you want that action to happen on the EDT (e.g. you need to show something in the UI you) can use `UITimer`.

Notice that the latter is `Form` specific which might be an advantage or disadvantage based on the app requirements. So if you change a `Form` the `UITimer` won't be bound and you would need to create a new one.